# Is There a Term for Database Operations That Don't Change Data?

Tags: database, terminology, operations, vocabulary

Is there a catch-all term for database operations that don't alter any data at all?

For example, `SELECT` statements have no effect on the contents of the database.

On the other hand, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, and `DELETE` statements have the potential to create, edit, or remove data.

To clarify, I'm not referring to *idempotent* operations, which can be repeated multiple times without altering data more than once.

Comment: there's the term "nilpotent", but I'm not sure anyone will understand you. I'd stick to "query operation"s.

Comment: non destructive operations?

Comment: nondestructive query.

Comment: "Nondestructive" excludes `INSERT` which doesn't destroy anything?

Comment: read-only?  or just SELECT.  In MS Access, fwiw, Insert/update/delete queries are referred to as 'Action' queries.

Comment: SQL is generally broken up into data manipulation, data definition, and data control statements.  Data manipulation statements are SELECT, INSERT, etc.  Data definition statements are ALTER, CREATE, etc.  Data control statements are GRANT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Section 4.22.2 of the [SQL92](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt) standard classifies statements that handle data as "SQL-data statements", out of which the statements that change data are a subcategory, "SQL-data change statements".
It does not, however, define a category for SQL-data statements that do **not** change any data.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the correct term for operations that don't change data is '**query**'.

And I believe the correct term for operations that do change data is '**command**', which may or may not be **idempotent**.

Further reading: [Command-query separation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation) on Wikipedia.